# Pythonic one-liner to populate a sequence

Tags: python

Say I want to calculate the first n Fibonacci numbers and put them into a list. With a 'for' loop, this is trivial. But is there a one-liner - a kind of list comprehension magic, perhaps - that could achieve this more elegantly?

I asked this question previously but it was shut down on the premise that it had already been answered. But neither of the suggested answers were actually answers to this particular question! They were of this form:

`fib = lambda n:reduce(lambda x,n:[x[1],x[0]+x[1]], range(n),[0,1])[0]`

Which yields the nth member of the sequence. I'm looking for a Pythonic one-line expression that outputs *a complete sequence*, i.e. not '3' but `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...]`

I'd like to reiterate that this isn't a *problem* I need a *solution* for. A simple 'for' loop does the job just fine. What I'm wondering is whether there's a preferred way of doing something like this in one line. This is not a 'code golf' question - it is not for curiosity's sake - it's about adding a new tool to the toolkit and deepening my understanding of the Pythonic idiom.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to something like `a = 1, 0; print([(a := [sum(a), a[0]])[1] for n in range(100)])`?

Comment: My 2 cents: just don't get caught up with one liners just for the sake of it...

Comment: @Julien every tool has its time and place, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will calculate the first `n` Fibonacci numbers.

```
n = 10
fibs = reduce(lambda x, _: x + [x[-2] + x[-1]], [0] * (n - 2), [0, 1])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - thank you! I knew I'd seen it somewhere but couldn't call it to the tip of my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the one liner you have already found to get an arbitrary element:

```py
>>> fib = lambda n: reduce(lambda x, _: [x[1], x[0] + x[1]], range(n), [0, 1])[0]
>>> fib(6)
8
```

And use it to fill a list with a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [reduce(lambda x, _: [x[1], x[0] + x[1]], range(n), [0, 1])[0] for n in range(10)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: A typical case of making code as inefficient as possible just for the sake of a one liner...

Comment: @Julien Yeah I wouldn't use something like this but hey it's what they asked for

Comment: Check out the accepted answer for a much better way of doing it! I agree that one-liners are rarely the right way to go, but if you think they *never* improve code readability... well, I'd eat my hat :)

Comment: @RohanSByrne Well in this case I think the one liner really decreases readability. Took me like 5 minutes after posting my answer to understand what it did.

Comment: Sure, but readability is a game of context and compromise. Can't show you the case I was working with, but I can assure you the readability of the script *as a whole* was very much enhanced by the compacting of one of its sub-parts into a single expression, even if that expression by itself was a little baroque.

Comment: @RohanSByrne I highly doubt that. Having a 5 line function defined, or even just having 5 lines of code grouped together by a lack of blank lines, will always be more readable than this jumble of `reduce` and `lambda`.

Comment: @nog642 yes, but you're missing the point. There are lots of cases where a hundred lines of code can be made more legible *as a whole* by compacting a handful of lines into one - yes, those compacted lines are much less readable by themselves, but the whole may be improved. If you've seriously never encountered a situation where this is so, I suggest you may be letting the perfect be the enemy of the good...

Comment: @RohanSByrne I cannot imagine such a scenario. There is no "making the whole program more readable by making parts of it less readable". A program being long does not make it unreadable; we have scrollbars. If long tasks need to be condensed to one line, we have functions.

Comment: @nog642 well firstly, if you don't think length relates to readability you should have a go at Les Miserables some day! Secondly, the visual length of a passage of code should be proportional to the significance of that passage to the overall purpose of the code. Spinning off a subfunction is okay, but that then forces someone to go find where that function is defined and read it there, disrupting the reader's train-of-thought. Compromises, compromises. And remember, not being able to imagine a use case doesn't mean it doesn't exist. In my case I'm looking at it right now :P